# Consistency in document schema in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to have different number of fields in documents of a collection in MongoDB ?

Like we can have the flexibility of having independent number of columns in a column family in HBase, is it possible to have variable schema in MongoDB too ?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Here's a summary of the advantages of a non-relational db straight [from Mongo](https://www.mongodb.com/compare/mongodb-mysql).

> Each document can store data with different attributes from other documents. As an example, consider a product catalog where a document storing details for an item of mens’ clothing will store different attributes from a document storing details of a tablet. This is a property commonly called “**polymorphism**”. With JSON documents, we can add new attributes when we need to, without having to alter a centralized database schema.

More about the [Polymorphic Pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-polymorphic-pattern).

> When all documents in a collection are of similar, but not identical, structure, we call this the Polymorphic Pattern. As mentioned, the Polymorphic Pattern is useful when we want to access (query) information from a single collection. Grouping documents together based on the queries we want to run (instead of separating the object across tables or collections) helps improve performance.

Reviewing [other Data Access Patterns](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-a-summary) before making a decision is useful. If documents in a collection are not identical in structure, performing updates and maintaining a front-end may be more challenging. However, polymorphic structure is useful:

> ...when there are a variety of documents that have more similarities than differences.

Comment: Thank you so much.